# Is there another way to handle arrow key input in Rust besides raw mode?

Tags: shell, rust

I am writing a small shell in Rust on Linux as an exercise and I wanted to implement command history as well as cursor moving (i.e. moving back the cursor to edit a typo in the command).

I did not find a way in the Rust standard library to handle arrow key events, but I found the [Termion](https://github.com/ticki/termion) crate which handles key events.

However, handling key events with Termion means entering "raw mode" for stdout, which overrides "legacy" functionalities, as described in [this article about the crate](http://ticki.github.io/blog/making-terminal-applications-in-rust-with-termion/):

> Without raw mode, you cannot write a proper interactive TTY application. Raw mode gives you complete control over the TTY:
>
> 1. It disables the line buffering: As you might notice, your command-line application tends to behave like the command-line. The programs will first get the input when the user types \n. Raw mode makes the program get the input after every key stroke.
> 2. It disables displaying the input: Without raw mode, the things you type appear on the screen, making it insufficient for most interactive TTY applications, where keys can represent controls and not textual input.
> 3. It disables canonicalization of the output: For example, \n represents “go one cell down” not “break the line”, for line breaks \n\r is needed.
> 4. It disables scrolling.

I find this solution a bit overkill, as I want to retain most of the "legacy" I/O functionalities. Is there another way to handle arrow key input, or will I need to use the raw mode?

Comment: What platforms are you limiting yourself to? Answers for Windows will probably be very different from Linux.

Comment: There could be interesting read about "how to do a shell" as this doesn't really specific to rust you should maybe search how other shell do it. But you are doing in a long run. You want to write a shell. This is something that could take more that 4-5 months to do.

Comment: [Magic search term: "readline"](https://crates.io/crates/rustyline) ?

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for the link, I'll check this

Comment: @Stargateur Sure, I know almost nothing about shells, and I was just doing a fun exercise to train on rust. I'm definitely going to read some papers & documentation on shells, this is very interesting. As for the original question, I'll surely find an answer while reading (and I'm going to look also at trentcl's crate). Thanks for the suggestion and the edit !

Comment: I'll promote that comment to an answer, but if it's not what you're looking for, don't feel obligated to accept it.

Comment: Just to add on to this for anyone else reading, the issue is that by default the operating system (i.e. Linux kernel) handles line editing for TTY input. It does this to make it easy to write simple CLI programs without needing to implement "readline" functionality in every application. If you don't want the kernel to handle input (i.e. you want to handle arrows yourself) then you have to disable the kernel's default behavior and use "raw mode." You don't get anything for free from the kernel in raw mode, but you can use a library that implements the features you need instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several crates that provide line editing features for interactive programs. Here are a few that I found by searching crates.io for "readline" (the name of a C library):

- [rustyline](https://crates.io/crates/rustyline) seems to be the most popular on crates.io.
- [liner](https://crates.io/crates/liner)
- [linefeed](https://crates.io/crates/linefeed)
- [linenoise-rust](https://crates.io/crates/linenoise-rust) is a set of Rust bindings to the [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise) library written in C.

I haven't used any of them, so this list is not a recommendation. Take a look at a few of them and choose one that suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, rustyline is exactly what I needed. Next time I'll search more thoroughly.